# Move an client (agent) to another deploymentgroup

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

In the past we had two different deployment groups A and B holding 3 "clients" (agents) each.

We would like to merge all clients of group B into group B, because the actual reason why we had 2 groups is gone now.

Is there a way other than removing and reconfiguring each of the clients? 
Unfortunately, I haven't found any feature in the UI of our on-premise Azure Devops Server 2019 Update 1.1 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deployment group is a logical set of deployment target machines that have agents installed on each one. Deployment groups represent the physical environments; for example, "Dev", "Test", "UAT", and "Production". In effect, a deployment group is just another grouping of agents, much like an agent pool.

We could also not be able to directly move agents across agent pool. Same here as deployment group.

So, it's not able to do this. Afraid you may have to remove and reconfigure each of the clients.

Comment: That's a shame. I would like to be able to do  that in the future. You have mentioned that it is "just" a grouping of agent. I am well aware of that. But thats why I am really curious if its hard to implement such feature in he future?